# How much latency can I expect from Apple Game Center connections?

Tags: game-center, latency

I would need a few bytes of data roughly every 0.1 seconds between players to have a smooth multiplayer snake game on iOS.

Is the iOS Game Center fast enough for this? What latency values can I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working on a real time pong type game using game center and it is more than fast enough to handle it, it should be fine for snake as long as you test that the connection between the players is good enough